# JPQL -- null to boolean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql, projection

Let's say I have an Entity

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "foos")
class Foo{
   @Id
   @Generatedvalue(strategy = IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "bar_id")
   private Bar bar;

   ...
}
```

and a Projection that should give me an `id` and a `boolean` telling me whether or not the instance has a `Bar`:

```java
interface FooProjection{
    String getId();
    Boolean hasBar();
}
```

How do you write the JPQL query?

I did try

```java
@Query(
    "SELECT"
    "   f.id,"
    "   (f.bar IS NOT NULL) AS bar"
    " FROM Foo f"
)
List<FooProjection> findProjections();
```

Which got me an `org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException` with the very helpful error message

> The expression is invalid, which means it does not follow the JPQL grammar.

How DO you write this query?

Comment: shouldn't it be like this `@Query(
    "SELECT f.id, f.bar AS bar FROM Foo f where f.bar IS NOT NULL"
)`

Comment: @pvpkiran no, I want a boolean that tells me WHETHER the `Foo` has a `Bar` or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if you should be running this query as you have it, but one fix for the syntax would be to use a `CASE` expression:

```
@Query(
    "SELECT"
    "   f.id,"
    "   CASE WHEN f.bar IS NOT NULL THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS bar"
    " FROM Foo f"
)
List<FooProjection> findProjections();
```